# ¿Cómo obtengo un valor especifico de un array multidimensional?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

El resultado de mi dd desde el controlador es el siguiente:

[image: Array]

Quisiera obtener el valor nombres de la clave user, asi:

```
        foreach ($var['user'] as $key) {
        dd($key['nombres']);
    }
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
 ErrorException in PaypalController.php line 177:
   Illegal string offset 'nombres'
```

Pero no me permite obtener nombres, no entiendo porque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código `$key` muestra `"nombres"`

Para obtener el valor de `"nombres"` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$var['user']['nombres']
```

Ya que el foreach recorre todo el array user.

Comment: Es correcto Pedro Prada! Agradecido amigo!